# JavaScript's equivalent to file_get_contents

Tags: javascript, file-get-contents, tampermonkey

In PHP we have a function called file_get_contents where it gets the content of a website and turns it into a string, but what about JavaScript? What is JavaScript's equivalent to file_get_contents? Is there one?

```
$string = file_get_contents("http://example.com/");
```

I do NOT have access to PHP, I'm using tampermonkey to edit this code, so it's JavaScript ONLY.

Comment: You're looking for AJAX.

Comment: @gforce301 I do not have access to PHP, I'm using this code on tampermonkey only, so it's strictly JavaScript only.

Answer (score 2):

For node, there's [`http.get()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback).

For modern browsers, there's [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

For older browsers, there's [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).